# GNU C++ error messages

Tags: gcc, documentation, g++, error-list

Is there a comprehensive list of error/warning messages for the g++ compiler available online?

I'm looking for something similar to the MSDN documentation which describes what each message means and possibly has some sample code which demonstrates the conditions which would cause such an error.

I've looked at the [GCC online documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/), but I don't see even a simple enumeration of all possible messages.

Comment: In the GCC source code, the file "<gcc-root-dir>/gcc/po/gcc.pot" seems to have all the error and warning messages. I think it is used for I18N. However, it doesn't have an explanation of what causes each message. https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/po/gcc.pot;h=4bf8920afe7236849d43caa984c6f760f2f212c8;hb=HEAD

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such list, only the GCC source code itself defines the messages.

Some of those messages are exercised by the GCC testsuite, so you can find some examples there, if you download the source code of GCC.  Of course they are written as functional and regression tests for GCC and not as a documentation for the user.