# gcc error message repository

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, gcc

I've spent a lot of time using the Microsoft compiler cl and found that the error codes that it gives in compile messages (like C1234, C5432, etc.) can be very useful.  When I get a error I'm unfamiliar with I can easily look it up on MSDN and get a more detailed explanation of what it means.

Now I'm using gcc almost exclusively and I find that I miss that feature.  When I get some error in gcc I seem to spend a lot of time googling for the text of the error for information about it.  Is there some repository of gcc error messages where each one is explained in more detail?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043379/gnu-c-error-messages/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that Googling the exact error message (omitting things that change, such as variable/function names) gives pretty good results. It sometimes helps to enclose all or part(s) of the error message in quotes so that it is treated as a sentence rather than a collection of words.

[This page](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_94.html) explains some of the more basic error messages.

If you encounter something particularly convoluted that you have trouble figuring out, you can of course always ask on SO.

Comment: Like with anything else, there's a learning curve. With time you'll find the vast majority of error straightforward, and the ones that one has to look up to be rare (the trickiest one of all are those where the error isn't what it seems.)

Comment: But that's exactly the point.  When I get an error I've never seen and it uses some cryptic phrasing it would be nice to have a quick way to look up the error without wondering how reliable the source of the information is.  Lots of errors like this are tied to a specific part of the C/C++ standards; getting a reference to where would be nice.  Is the answer to the question no, there's no repository or reference, or are you just unaware of one?

Comment: While I'll be happy to be proven otherwise, it should be pretty clear by now that no such thing exists. Besides, this same question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043379/gnu-c-error-messages/

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of any complete repository including full explanations, but for myself:

- Over time you'll learn what particular error messages mean (especially in terms of "you're missing a `;` but the compiler can't tell").
- Googling for the constant part of the error message in quotes (not including function names for example) often gives very good explanations in the first 3-5 hits.
- Template related errors are usually the worst. For those, the compiler gives you two line numbers: The place the template code exists, and the place it's being instantiated. Looking at both lines of code in context can often make things far more clear ("Why is it using THAT overload?"). Sometimes the simplest way is to create a test program with way simpler types to work out what the compiler's telling you (since it won't be helpful enough to show typedefs in the error message).
- If it's a small piece of code, try it in a different compiler (for example Comeau online) and see if the error is clearer.