# List of all possible g++ errors

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

Is there anywhere I can find a list of most (or all) g++ errors or error categories? I have look around and can't seem to find anything interesting.

In case there isn't such a list, what would you recommend? I'm currently coding a C++ error steamroller that uses g++ to check for errors.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043379/gnu-c-error-messages

Comment: Ib4 *"That answer over there is old"*: You can raise a bounty on that question if you feel like it needs a more up-to-date one.

Comment: I'm OK with that answer. Thank you.